# only fully recursive checkout includes externals

Tags: svn

I am checking out an SVN repository including externals (svn:externals property).

But, apparently, if I use --depth with any value other than 'infinity', the externals are not downloaded. This is especially ironic, since apparently it is possible to update later with --set-depth exclude and exclude folders later.

Is it possible to check out selectively *and* include all externals?

Comment: What `--depth` setting are you using? There are four I know of: _none_, _files_, _immediates_, and _infinity_. Except for the last, none of these will checkout a sub-directory tree let alone an `svn:externals` link. What exactly are you expecting? I can use `svn co --set-depth=infinity` to _checkout_ an external, but that's like updating a directory.

Comment: Example: svn co --depth immediates
Expected: all files in the root directory are created, and for each directory in the root directory, an empty directory is created.
Actual: all files in the root directory are created, and for each directory in the root directory _except the externals_ , an empty directory is created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same problem and I don’t have any real answer except the workaround checking out the externals manually afterwards.

```
mkdir wc
svn co http://example.com/svn/repo/trunk wc --depth=immediates
cd wc
svn co http://example.com/svn/extrepo external --depth=empty
```

But obviously, this defeats the whole purpose of externals.

This behavior was reported in the Subversion issue tracker as [Issue 3311](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-3311), where it was noted

> This was an explicitly defined feature. (There is code to check for this condition and then explicitly skip handling)

(However, the issue was not closed and still has *Status: NEW*.)

And I was not able to find any explicit reason for this “feature”, I found only [the commit which introduced it](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_client/update.c?r1=864067&r2=864068&) by swapping checks for the old `--non-recursive` option with a check for `depth == svn_depth_infinity`, which is a bit too strict, I would say, but it has essentially stayed there ever since.

Comment: this suggestion isn't good. If do full recursive, the externals are properly setup, and if I `svn update` then externals are also updated. If I do sparse checkout and manually checkout externals, as suggested here, the `svn update` won't work for manually checked out externals. SVN is major POS in dealing with externals, so frustrating.

Comment: Well, _of course_ this isn’t good. As I say: I don’t have a real answer, except an (ugly, half-working, “this defeats the whole purpose of externals”) workaround I use in such cases, and an explanation that the functionality is just not there right now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm experiencing the same issue and I don't have a solution, but I think I've at least found a partial workaround.

First I'd like to address David W's question about why this is a problem.
I understand where he is coming from in thinking that, if you're picking specific directories you want to checkout, you may assume that you DON'T want ANY other directories checked out ergo, no externals.

HOWEVER, that is not ALWAYS the case.  For example, we have multiple development projects that are all related to a third party package.  We have a directory that has one external directory that links to the third party product repository and then at the same level as that directory, we have separate directories for different projects we develop related to that 3rd party project.  At any given time I may only want to work on ONE of our projects and I don't want to check out the other dozen or so projects, BUT all of our project have relative path references "back" to the 3rd party project directory.  So, anytime I checkout one of our projects, I want to make sure that the external link to the 3rd party project also get checked out.

This is the scenario in our shop where, we need sparse checkout but we want any externals that are attached to any of the directories in the sparse checkout chain to be checked out as well.

Now, for the partial workaround....

What I found was, after I use TortoiseSVN to do the initial sparse check out,(which doesn't get my externals) if I then go to the command prompt and execute the following while in the directory above the directory the external property was associated with (Not sure yet if that fact is relevant but figured it was worth mentioning since others say they didn't get similar results using svn up):

```
svn up --depth infinity
```

it will check out my externals (note that it did NOT pull down any of the directories that I had not selected when I picked my sparse checkout to begin with).  SO this got me where I wanted to be.

This is "BETTER" but definitely is still not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, I have used a bit of cmd/bat windows shell scripting to read the external definition and create its missing checkout. It's a bit like @Mormegil's answer except that I read the external's URL instead of hardcoding it.

```
cd folderWithExternal

rem Read line from svn:external and put it in temporary file
svn propget svn:externals  | findstr myExternalName > external.tmp

rem Put content of temporary file in variable
set /p external=<external.tmp

rem Create a checkout for the external. The ^^ is to deal with cmd escaping.
svn checkout ^^%external%
```

This example assumes that the external definition is given in the svn:externals property in this format:

```
^/elsewhere/foo@123 myExternalName
```

I had to add those `^^` in my script to work around the fact that `^` is an escape character in windows cmd. In SVN externals it means "root of the same repository".

In my use case I also had to checkout certain externals but not others, which is why I look for a specific external. You could of course instead loop through all the lines in the external and create sparse checkouts for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I created a folder with the same name as the external folder, then defined the externals inside this.
Then the folder is available for selective checkout.

Answer (score -1):

> Example: svn co --depth immediates Expected: all files in the root directory are created, and for each directory in the root directory, an empty directory is created. Actual: all files in the root directory are created, and for each directory in the root directory except the externals , an empty directory is created.

I think I understand your issue, but I'm not sure how this is a problem. The purpose of the `svn co --depth` and `svn update --set-depth` is to allow you to do sparse checkouts which allows you to manipulate your repository structure without having to checkout gigabytes of files you're really not interested in.

Here are two examples of using sparse checkouts:

- As a CM, I work in almost all of our projects at one time or another. On my system, I did a `svn co --depth=immediates $REPO/trunk` which allows me to see all of our projects under trunk, but it doesn't use a lot of disk space and it didn't take that long to checkout. I can then go into the project that needs my attention and do a `svn up --set-depth=infinity` to get that project. Having the entire repository checked out like this allows me to manipulate our projects (rename them, delete obsolete ones, etc.).
- At my last job, I refactored our branches and tags after a CVS to SVN conversion. Thousands of branches and tags were created that were absolutely meaningless. I did a `svn co --set-depth=empty $REPO` and then `svn up --set-depth=immediates branches tags. Now I had a directory of all of our tags and branches, but none of the files underneath them. I could remove obsolete branches and tags, and rename them into more meaningful names.

What you're complaining about is that if I do a `svn checkout --depth=immediates`, I don't get an ***empty*** externals directory. But that directory doesn't actually exist in your project. It's simply a magic trick performed by Subversion. What would be the use of an empty externals directory?

As a CM, I'm one of the few people who do sparse checkouts. It's not something most developers usually do. When I do a sparse checkout, I really don't want to see externals directories. If for some reason, you need to know where externals directories exist, you can do `svn plist -vR svn:externals .` and get the complete list, and then do a `svn up --set-depth=infinity $extern_dir`.

Comment: _What you're complaining about is that [...] I don't get an empty externals directory. [...]What would be the use of an empty externals directory?_ The use would be the ability to update that and that only without having to update the rest. Even more, without having to check out the rest in the first place.

The final goal is to make a sparse checkout with externals. But, judging from the answer, SVN does not support that model: you do a full checkout with externals, or you do a sparse checkout which always excludes all externals. Is that really so?

Comment: I tried this: after svn co --depth=immediate, I changed dir, typed svn propget svn:externals to get the list of external URLs and local mappings, then tried svn up --set-depth=infinity <one of the local mappings>. Nothing was downloaded. Then tried --set-depth=infinity <one of the external URLs>. Error: <one of the external URLs> is not a local path. Using svn 1.7.9 command-line included within TortoiseSVN